# R for cj_tidy function

Tags: r

I have a dataset called cojoint_data_a which has 100 columns with 14 forced-choice decision tasks, with 7 features each. It has 100 rows with one additional column for "ID" and 14x2x8 (one additional column called "Rating" is another measurement of outcome but my references put in this way so I follow them) feature columns, plus 14 columns for 14 forced-choice outcome variable.

I try to do use cj_tidy function but it keeps showing below error:

```
# profile_variables

list1 <- list(
Purpose = list(
~ purpose_a1 + purpose_a2 + purpose_a3 + purpose_a4 + purpose_a5 + purpose_a6 + purpose_a7 + purpose_a8 + purpose_a9 + purpose_a10 + purpose_a11 + purpose_a12 + purpose_a13 + purpose_a14,
~ purpose_b1 + purpose_b2 + purpose_b3 + purpose_b4 + purpose_b5 + purpose_b6 + purpose_b7 + purpose_b8 + purpose_b9 + purpose_b10 + purpose_b11 + purpose_b12 + purpose_b13 + purpose_b14
),
Flight = list(
~ flight_a1 + flight_a2 + flight_a3 + flight_a4 + flight_a5 + flight_a6 + flight_a7 + flight_a8 + flight_a9 + flight_a10 + flight_a11 + flight_a12 + flight_a13 + flight_a14,
~ flight_b1 + flight_b2 + flight_b3 + flight_b4 + flight_b5 + flight_b6 + flight_b7 + flight_b8 + flight_b9 + flight_b10 + flight_b11 + flight_b12 + flight_b13 + flight_b14
),
Econ = list(
~ econ_a1 + econ_a2 + econ_a3 + econ_a4 + econ_a5 + econ_a6 + econ_a7 + econ_a8 + econ_a9 + econ_a10 + econ_a11 + econ_a12 + econ_a13 + econ_a14,
~ econ_b1 + econ_b2 + econ_b3 + econ_b4 + econ_b5 + econ_b6 + econ_b7 + econ_b8 + econ_b9 + econ_b10 + econ_b11 + econ_b12 + econ_b13 + econ_b14
),
Civil = list(
~ civil_a1 + civil_a2 + civil_a3 + civil_a4 + civil_a5 + civil_a6 + civil_a7 + civil_a8 + civil_a9 + civil_a10 + civil_a11 + civil_a12 + civil_a13 + civil_a14,
~ civil_b1 + civil_b2 + civil_b3 + civil_b4 + civil_b5 + civil_b6 + civil_b7 + civil_b8 + civil_b9 + civil_b10 + civil_b11 + civil_b12 + civil_b13 + civil_b14
),
AI = list(
~ ai_a1 + ai_a2 + ai_a3 + ai_a4 + ai_a5 + ai_a6 + ai_a7 + ai_a8 + ai_a9 + ai_a10 + ai_a11 + ai_a12 + ai_a13 + ai_a14,
~ ai_b1 + ai_b2 + ai_b3 + ai_b4 + ai_b5 + ai_b6 + ai_b7 + ai_b8 + ai_b9 + ai_b10 + ai_b11 + ai_b12 + ai_b13 + ai_b14
),
Ally = list(
~ ally_a1 + ally_a2 + ally_a3 + ally_a4 + ally_a5 + ally_a6 + ally_a7 + ally_a8 + ally_a9 + ally_a10 + ally_a11 + ally_a12 + ally_a13 + ally_a14,
~ ally_b1 + ally_b2 + ally_b3 + ally_b4 + ally_b5 + ally_b6 + ally_b7 + ally_b8 + ally_b9 + ally_b10 + ally_b11 + ally_b12 + ally_b13 + ally_b14
),
IO = list(
~ io_a1 + io_a2 + io_a3 + io_a4 + io_a5 + io_a6 + io_a7 + io_a8 + io_a9 + io_a10 + io_a11 + io_a12 + io_a13 + io_a14,
~ io_b1 + io_b2 + io_b3 + io_b4 + io_b5 + io_b6 + io_b7 + io_b8 + io_b9 + io_b10 + io_b11 + io_b12 + io_b13 + io_b14
),
Rating = list(
~ rating_a1 + rating_a2 + rating_a3 + rating_a4 + rating_a5 + rating_a6 + rating_a7 + rating_a8 + rating_a9 + rating_a10 + rating_a11 + rating_a12 + rating_a13 + rating_a14,
~ rating_b1 + rating_b2 + rating_b3 + rating_b4 + rating_b5 + rating_b6 + io_b7 + rating_b8 + rating_b9 + rating_b10 + rating_b11 + rating_b12 + rating_b13 + rating_b14
)
)

# task variables

list2 <- list(choice = ~ choice_1 + choice_2 + choice_3 + choice_4 + choice_5 + choice_6 + choice_7+ choice_8 + choice_9 + choice_10 + choice_11 + choice_12 + choice_13 + choice_14)

reintegration.data <- cj_tidy(conjoint_data_a, profile_variables = list1, task_variables = list2, id = ~ Respondent)

Error in `[[<-`:
! Assigned data `halfstack[[names(task_variables)[i]]]` must be
compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 14 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 100 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 100 to size 14.
-

Backtrace:
▆

1. └─cregg::cj_tidy(...)
2. ├─base::`[[<-`(...)
3. └─tibble:::`[[<-.tbl_df`(...)
4.     └─tibble:::tbl_subassign(...)
5.       └─tibble:::vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows(value, fast_nrow(xo), i_arg = NULL, value_arg, call)

lengths_list1 <- sapply(list1, function(x) length(unlist(x)) == n_rows)
lengths_list2 <- sapply(list2, function(x) length(unlist(x)) == n_rows)

print(lengths_list1)
print(lengths_list2)
```

Also, verification of this shows all FALSE. I think all profile and task variables are fine.